# Styles are not getting applied to HTML injected via network call

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

In my angular 8.1.3 application, I am injecting HTML div, I want to apply styles to the classes used in that HTML payload.

But styles are not getting applied unless I put them in root level CSS of the project. (Which I dont want to do)

Sub-component.html

```
<div id="ImgBlock" class="col-xs-12">
      <div> [innerHTML]="ImagePayload"></div>
</div>
```

here is my Sub-component.ts

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'SubComponent',
      templateUrl: './SubComponent.html',
      styleUrls: ['./SubComponent.scss'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })

    export class SubComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
     public ImagePayload: string;

     // Constructros and other functions

    }
```

here is the parent component which creates an instance of sub-component and injects HTML payload in ImagePayload variable.

```
       @Component({
       selector: 'parentComponent',
       templateUrl: './parentComponent.html',
       styleUrls: ['./parentComponent.scss'],
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
     })
     export class parentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 

    showImage(data: Somedata) {
      const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
       title: 'recognise Image data ',
       content: SubComponent,
    });

      const info = dialog.content.instance;
      info.ImagePayload = data.challenge;
    }
   }
```

Here is a css style for class used in imagePayload variable.

```
  input.Image_selection_checkbox {
            width: 15px;
        }
```

I applied the same style to

1) SubComponent.scss

2) parentComponent.scss

3) app.component.scss
    (of parentCompoent)

4) style.scss of this particular sub-project
    (Project have multiple sub-project as well)

but none of them are getting applied !

But when I put the same style in root style.scss (of the main project directory!)
It is getting applied.

I am having a limited idea about role of encapsulation. Is that a culprit?

what are the other issues?